# How to get and display menu items except the parent item?

Tags: blocks, navigation

Let's say my menu tree is like below:

- Parent

  - Sub-Parent

    - Child

I want to get the Sub-Parent title and all child's title and url.

How can I do it in Drupal 8?

I have looked at [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224593/how-to-display-a-block-with-menu-child-items-programmatically) but it just for getting the parent, it is not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a block with menu child items programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224593/how-to-display-a-block-with-menu-child-items-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the answer you mentioned, I assume that you would like to retrieve your items data programmatically.

What you are missing is the `setRoot()` method from `MenuTreeParameters` ([here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuTreeParameters.php/function/MenuTreeParameters%3A%3AsetRoot/8.2.x)). Here is how you could start with:

```
    $menuTree = \Drupal::menuTree();

    $menuTreeParameters = new MenuTreeParameters();
    // This will fetch the tree starting from your Sub-Parent
    $menuTreeParameters->setRoot('sub_parent_link_plugin_ID');
    // Set the nb of levels, starting from root you defined, that you want to fetch (0 = all)
    $menuTreeParameters->setMaxdepth(1);

    // Load tree based on your parameters
    $myMenuTree = $menuTree->load('name_of_your_menu', $menuTreeParameters);
    // List of Sub-parent children items
    $subtree = $myMenuTree['sub_parent_link_plugin_ID']->subtree;
```

`$myMenuTree` will give you data about Sub-Parent as a MenuLinkTreeElement. 
`$subtree` will correspond to its children, each as a MenuLinkTreeElement as well.

In each of these two variables, you will find for each MenuLinkTreeElement a `link` entry of type `MenuLinkContent` containing all the data about your menu link item.
Starting from `link`, you would be able to use the `MenuLinkContent` [methods](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21src%21Entity%21MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/8.2.x) to retrieve the title and url of each of your items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for reply late because I was trying other solutions these few days. And thank you so much! Your solution is the most easiest one and it works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by configuring the `Menu levels` on your Menu Block and placing that Block in a region of your theme. Additionally configure the Visibility of the block so it only appears on pages where you want it.

You can learn more about the Menu levels configuration here: [Drupal 8 Navigation Menu Blocks configuration](https://prkos.hr/Primary-and-Secondary-Navigation-Drupal-8#drupal-8-navigation-menu-blocks-configuration).

In your case you want the **Initial visibility level** and **Number of levels to display** to be either:

`1` and `3`

OR

`2` and `3`

AND

you'll want the **Expand all menu items** to be checked, unless you have all the items Expanded under Menu settins.